# Why does this loop repeat each iteration twice?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, async-await, repeat

The function below prints each number twice. Could someone explain how it works? I tried debugging but all I can see is that the value of `i` only increases on every second iteration.

```js
async function run(then) {
    for (let i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        console.log(i);
        then = await { then };
    }
}

run(run);
```

Concretely speaking, there are two things I don't understand.

- Why does `i` not increase on every single iteration?
- What does `then = await { then };` exactly do? My first guess was that it would wait for a nested async call to `run` to finish before moving on to the next iteration, but this does not seem to be the case.

Comment: It's more related to the `run(run);`

Comment: Removing `then = await { then };` seems to work

Comment: @VLAZ Aren't, you the person from the `Suggested edit queue is full` question?

Comment: @K.KDesgins The question is "why does it work this way", not "how do I fix it".

Comment: @K.KDesgins Yes, Hi.

Comment: Await doesn't care if it's in a loop before running the next iteration. All the iterations of the loop run immediately and whatever `then` is being reassigned to is just whatever arbitrary value is that last of the iterations to finish.

Comment: @JakeAve that is wrong and the `await` is *crucial* for how this code operates.

Comment: If you want to run something then wait for the next, you have to use recursion or an array of promises and a `Promise.all` / `Promise.allSettled`

Comment: The { then } looks like a [custom thenable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await#thenable_objects). Very clever. I wonder what's the origin of this.

Comment: @JakeAve that is also wrong. `await` will sleep the entire function execution. Whether it's a loop or not is irrelevant. While the function is suspended it doesn't run.

Comment: @WiktorZychla bingo!

Comment: I almost see this as an interview question to a position that should remain open.

Comment: @WiktorZychla "*to a position that should remain open.*" very well said :D

Comment: @VLAZ you're right about my mistake. It's definitely executing the `run` function twice. Maybe it has to do with reassigning the variable.

Comment: While you're at it, explain this 
`const run = async (then) => {
  console.log("run");
  for (let i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    console.log(i);
    const notThen = await { then };
  }
};

run(run);`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We can make this a bit clearer with minor re-write to include logging:

```js
async function run(callback) {
    let then = callback;
    for (let i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        console.log(callback === run ? "A" : "B", i);
        then = await { then };
    }
}

run(run);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

This shows there are actually *two* loops started. For simplicity just called A and B. They log and `await` which means that their logs interleave and lead to A 1, B 1, A 2, B 2, etc.

This happens because of the first statement: `run(run)`. Which passes the same function as a callback to itself. This does not *call* the callback but it is the first step to unravelling this.

---

The next step to understanding what is happening is `await`. You can `await` any value and in *most cases* if it's not a promise, it doesn't matter. If you have `await 42;` it just pretends the value was `Promise.resolve(42)` and continues the operation immediately with the next tick. That is true for *most* non-promises. The only exception is [thenables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await#thenable_objects) - objects which have a `.then()` method.

When a thenable is awaited, its `then()` method is called:

```js
const thenable = {
  then() {
    console.log("called");
  }
};

(async () => {
  await thenable;
})()
```

Which then explains the `await { then }` statement. This uses the shorthand for `{ then: then }` where `then` is the callback passed to `run`. Thus it creates a thenable object which, when awaited, will execute the callback.

This means that the first time `run()` is executed and on the first iteration of the loop A the code is effectively `await { then: run }` which will execute `run` again which then starts loop B.

The value of `then` is overridden each time, hence why it only ever runs two loops in parallel, rather than more.

---

There is more to thenables that is relevant to fully grasp this code. I showed a simple one before which just shows that awaiting it calls the method. However, in reality `await thenable` will call `.then()` with two parameters - functions that can be called for success and failure. In the same way that the Promise constructor does it.

```js
const badThenable = {
  then() {
    console.log("bad called");
  }
};

(async () => {
  await badThenable;
  console.log("never reached");
})();

const goodThenable = {
  then(resolve, reject) { //two callbacks
    console.log("good called");
    resolve(); //at least one needs to be called
  }
};

(async () => {
  await goodThenable;
  console.log("correctly reached");
})();
```

This is relevant because `run()` expects a callback and when the `await { then: run }` executes it calls `run(builtInResolveFunction)` which then gets passed to the next `await { then: builtInResolveFunction }` which in turn resolves causes the a `await` to resolve.

---

With all this aside, the interleaved logging is just a factor of how tasks resolve:

```js
(async () => {
  for (let i = 1; i <= 10; i++){
    console.log("A", i);
    await Promise.resolve("just to force a minimal wait");
  } 
})();

(async () => {
  for (let i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    console.log("B", i);
    await Promise.resolve("just to force a minimal wait");
  } 
})();
```

If there are two async functions running and there is nothing to really wait for:

1. One would run until it reaches an `await` and will then be suspended.
2. The other would run until it reaches an `await` and will then be suspended.
3. Repeat 1. and 2. until there are no more awaits.

Comment: I love how such a small/simple looking code-snippet can have so much depth. Well explained. :-)

Comment: @Ivar there is actually a bit more. But it's bed time. And tomorrow is a bit busy for me. I'll try to add as soon as possible. Essentially, A and B toss the resolver function to each other and calling `await` on it *resolves the other `await`* and allows the other loop to continue. So, for example for `i = 3` in A the `await { then }` resolves the `await { then }` in B for `i = 2`. This back and forth not only allows the whole thing to work, it also means that for B `i = 10` the await never resolves because A has finished. I want to draw up a sequence diagram for it for better illustration.

Comment: I believe you could improve the fragment that explains why there's no infinite recursion. It' not entirely clear at the moment.

Comment: @WiktorZychla because `run(run)` is executed once and inside the `await { then: run }` is also executed once. The `then = await {then}` reassigns it. But each time `await { then }` is called it actually passes in the resolver function to the `.then()` method. It's a bit hard to grasp, since it's a lot of stuff happening at once. It's hard to fully and clearly explain. The next seciton which starts with "*There is more to thenables that is relevant to fully grasp this code.*"  explains the resolver stuff. I wanted to explain one concept at a time. The `await` line just does so much here.

Comment: Thanks. In retrospect it's pretty obvious to me that there must be two loops running alternatingly to give the illusion of repeated iterations. I've never thought that it is possible to change the flow of async code using the callback functions of the awaited promises, but that also makes perfect sense. I'm still trying to figure out how the two loops alternate. When I call `run(run(run))` (3 times `run`) I get a more complex, but still reproducible pattern.